# ctrl + space do eclipse (No Default Proposals), novas classes criadas o assistente não funciona

Tags: eclipse

Estou atualmente utilizando o Eclipse Luna, logo que realizei o update (SVN) em minha aplicação e criei uma nova classe, simplesmente meus atributos junto com o auto complete do eclipse (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>) não funcionam mais.

O que mais me intriga é que em todas outras classes na qual realizo o `ctrl +space` em algum objeto/atributo/variável o mesmo funciona!

Apenas não funciona quando crio novas classes.

Já apaguei o `.metadata` do *work space* e não obtive resultado, assim como marquei a opção (*Java Proposals* e *Java Non-Type-Proposals*) em *Window* -> *Preferences* -> *Java* -> *Editor* -> *Content Assist* -> *Advanced*, mas não obtive resultado.

Alguém sabe que diabos pode estar ocorrendo?

Comment: Já tentou escrever tudo manualmente e verificar se o Eclipse retorna algum erro?

Comment: sim, mas nenhum erro é retornado @mutley.

Comment: Se você não escreveu nada e tenta usar o auto complete, ele não consegue retornar o que você quer, na maioria das vezes. Mas se você escreve a primeira letra, ele já dá alguns resultados.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problema resolvido.

Acabei criando um outro *workspace* e baixando meu projeto pelo *SVN* novamente e "magicamente" o *code assistant* voltar a funcionar corretamente.